# Can I use 2 separate SSL certificates for 1 domain name?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've noticed it is a lot cheaper to buy a single website SSL certificate than a wildcard certificate.

My question is if I have 2 applications setup in IIS:
1. website.com
2. subdomain.website.com

Firstly, would I be able to buy 2 individual certificates for the website.com and subdomain.website.com?

Secondly, assuming I was able to buy the above certs, would it actually work?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. The domain name is recorded in CN field (single domain or a wildcard). There is also SAN extension that allows you to use the same certificate on different domains (sub.domain.com and domain.com are considered two different domains).